# Get the return value of a anonymous function of another function to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, return-value, anonymous-function

in this code, the anonymous function of the readFile function returns a value. What i want to do is get that return value to a separate variable.

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var file = '../data/tc.json';

jsonfile.readFile(file, function (error, data) {
    return data;
  });
```

Comment: `readFile` is `asynchronous`.. Instead of doing `return`, use it or pass it as argument for another `function`

Comment: See also: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)